# For-loop or std::any_of, which one should I use?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, stl, idioms

I can't decide between a *for-loop* and *std::any_of*, e.g:

```cpp
QString fileName = "Whatever";  // might contain a key-string which is part of sMyStringlist()
auto anyTypeContains = [&](const QString& categoryStr)
{
    for(auto const &keyStr : sMyStringlist()[categoryStr])
        if(fileName.contains(keyStr, Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            return true;
    return false;
};
if(anyTypeContains("myCategory"))
...
```

or

```cpp
QString fileName = "Whatever";  // might contain a key-string which is part of sMyStringlist()
auto anyTypeContains = [&](const QString& categoryStr)
{
    return std::any_of(
                sMyStringlist()[categoryStr].begin(),
                sMyStringlist()[categoryStr].end(),
                [&](const QString& keyStr){
        return fileName.contains(keyStr, Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    });
};
if(anyTypeContains("myCategory"))
...
```

I think the *for-loop* might be better since everyone should be familiar with it. Is there any reason for using *any_of* or is it just a matter of taste? Are there other (better) alternatives? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would use the most expressive (`std::any_of`) and everybody should be (or become) familiar with the standard algorithms.

Comment: With `std::any_of` you could provide an [execution policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) to add e.g. possible parallelization.

Comment: Unrelated, in the second case, shouldn't lambda accept keyStr by const reference?

Comment: In my mind, the only reason to _not_ use the standard algorithms is that they don't support taking a container and applying the algorithm on its full range, example: `std::any_of(container, [](const auto& elem) { ... });` ... but I try using them as much as possible anyway.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: 1. It's easy to write a few container adapters for standard algorithms, so that you can write `mystd_extras::any_of(container, predicate)`

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica Yes. I've done that sometimes in the past, but nowadays I usually just use the algorithm as it is. It'd be a nice addition to have standardized though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: In C++20, you can just use [`std::ranges::any_of(container, predicate)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/all_any_none_of).

Comment: @Galik: Also if *<algorithm>* must be included just for that reason? Okay if it's opinion-based or just a matter of taste is kind of answered by the appropriate tag now. Didn't know that before.

Comment: @smitsyn: Thanks for the advice. I changed it, also the closure to *[&]*.

Comment: @Agent49 I would find it very hard to write much code without including `<algorithm>`. But regardless, including a header doesn't cost anything if you don't use anything from it. And you only pay for what you do use. So if you only call `std::any_of` that is the only thing that will get compiled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many C++ standard library functions (typically those in `<algorithm>`) are there to obviate the need for `for` or other loop constructs. `std::accumulate` is an early example.

Therefore prefer `std::any_of` rather than a loop.